# Pyspark session configuration overwriting

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I recently come across below program , after new session values are declared in variable , why stopping spark context ?

usually , spark session will be stopped at the end but here , why stopping after new configuration declaration ?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("MyApp") \
.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost") \
.getOrCreate()
default_conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
print(default_conf)
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'),
                                    ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'),
                                    ('spark.executor.cores', '4'),
                                    ('spark.cores.max', '4'),
                                    ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])

spark.sparkContext.stop()
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("MyApp") \
.config(conf=conf) \
.getOrCreate()
default_conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.cores.max")
print("updated configs " , default_conf)
```

I am trying to understand

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only example code to show that you cannot modify running session config. You can create it, get the config that was generated, then stop and recreate with updated values.

Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense, because you'd just use the config you needed from the beginning...

`default_conf` variable at the end is only the cores setting, however.